# image link doesn't work. I've got images as links and one of them only works

Tags: html, image, hyperlink

I have images as links, one of them works- it's this div with mail class. I don't know what's going on, everything looks just fine :-/

```
    <div class="face">
        <a href="www.facebook.com" target="_blanket"><img src="https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/free-social-icons/67/facebook_circle_black-128.png" width="5%">
        </a>
   </div>
    <div class="twitter">
        <a href="www.twitter.com"><img src="http://www.evilthemovie.com/images/twitter.jpg" width="16%">
        </a>
   </div>
    <div class="mail">
        <a href="www.gmail.com" target="_blanket"><img src="http://pickering-communications.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/02/iconmonstr-email-9-icon-1_zpsf6261ecf.png" width="11%">
       </a>
    </div>

    .face{ position:relative; top: -230px; left: 300px; } 
    .twitter{ position: absolute; top:22px; left: 900px; } 
    .mail{ position: absolute; top: 21px; left: 883px; }
```

Comment: Please post your html and css

Comment: <div class="face">
    <a href="www.facebook.com" target="_blanket"><img src="https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/free-social-icons/67/facebook_circle_black-128.png" width="5%"></a>
 </div>
  <div class="twitter"><a href="www.twitter.com"><img src="http://www.evilthemovie.com/images/twitter.jpg" width="16%"></a></div>
<div class="mail"><a href="www.gmail.com" target="_blanket"><img src="http://pickering-communications.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/02/iconmonstr-email-9-icon-1_zpsf6261ecf.png" width="11%"></a></div>

Comment: .face{
  position:relative;
  top: -230px;
  left: 300px;
}
.twitter{
  position: absolute;
  top:22px;
    left: 900px;
}
.mail{
  position: absolute;
  top: 21px;
  left: 883px;
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`face` has a `-230 top` position, so it's off the screen. `twitter` nearly has the same x position of `mail` so they are on top of each other.

I changed your css a bit and now you should be able to see all three:

```
   .face{ position:relative; top: 22px; left: 300px; } 
    .twitter{ position: absolute; top:22px; left: 600px; } 
    .mail{ position: absolute; top: 21px; left: 900px; }
```

example:http://codepen.io/nilestanner/pen/dpyQvZ